# getText() return empty string in Edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this strange behaviour in `EditText`.

I have created a class that extend `EditText` then I have make a method in this new class called validate and in this method I am trying to validate the text user enter in the `EditText` with some conditions.

The problem is that `getText()` is returning empty string all the time. Here's my code :

```
public class AttributeNumber extends EditText {
    public boolean validate () {
        Log.i("AMIRA", "Text Out" + getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: are you passing a number to the edittext ? or its string value?

Comment: @PramodPatel I am passing number to it, I have set it is input type to number, would it make any difference

Comment: Your `validate()` method needs to be put inside some listener which gets called when the text changes, `validate()` won't call itself

Comment: @AmanGrover Yes I call validate inside onClick Listener of Button, when press button I call validate on the edittext.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail is there any specific reason for creating `AttributeNumber` class by extending `EditText`? You can easily write a `validate()` method in your `Fragment` or `Activity` rather than creating a custom `EditText`.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail `onClick()` will only run when the button is clicked, and at that time the `getText()` *is* null. You need to call `validate()` inside `addTextChangedListener()`

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail what do you want to check for in your `validate()` method?

Comment: im not sure.. but the getText() method isn't it supposed to be called by a TextView or something? e.g TextView.getText().toString(); u seem like calling juz that function without attaching it to any element here.

Comment: may be it should be `this.getText().toString()`

Comment: @AmitTiwari yes AttributeNumber class has many things to do in the style , drawable images, and also is a dynamic class that add on runtime with all these customization.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail ok, got it. try my above comment. Haven't created custom `EditText` but I guess you need the reference to the `EditText` for calling the `getText()` method, so `this.getText().toString()` might work.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail Do you customizing setText() or getText() in AttributeNumber class?  It's good works by EditText.getText().toString()!. I may guess that you are a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class AttributeNumber extends EditText {
    public boolean validate () {
        Log.i("AMIRA", "Text Out" + AttributeNumber.this.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your validate() method.
It has a missing return statement.

```
public class AttributeNumber extends EditText {
    public boolean validate () {
        Log.i("AMIRA", "Text Out" + getText().toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```